# Solve $\int_0^{r_0} \sqrt{2m(E-\frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 r^2))} \, r^2 \, dr$

Tags: integration

I have to solve the following integral for a exercise in quantum mechanics:
$$\int_0^{r_0} \sqrt{2m(E-\frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 r^2))} \, r^2 \, dr$$
but I don't know how to do it. 
$$r_0 = \sqrt{\frac{2E}{m\omega^2}}$$
We got following hint on our exercise sheet:
$$ \int_0^1 x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = \int_0^1 x^2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1} dx = \frac{\pi}{16} $$

Comment: Have you tried any approach yet?

Comment: No, I don't really know how to approach it. Considering the hint we got it should be solvable by substitution, but I dont know how to substitute.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know, if this integral is correct. It is part of a bigger question about the density of states of a particle in a 3D harmonic oscillator potential I asked on the Physics page.

Comment: A change of variables $r = r_0 x$ might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I:=\int _0^{r_0}\sqrt{2m(E-\frac{1}{2} m w^2r^2)}r^2 \, dr \\= \sqrt{2mE} \int_0^{r_0} \sqrt{1-\frac{mw^2}{2E}r^2}r^2\, dr =  \sqrt{2mE} \int_0^{r_0} \sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{r_0^2}}r^2\, dr$$

Set $x=r/r_0$. then
$$I=\sqrt{2mE} \int_0^1 r_0\sqrt{1-x^2}(xr_0)^2 \, dx= r_0^3\sqrt{2mE}\frac{\pi}{16}= \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{E^2}{m w^3}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will first try it by myself with the hint given by Robert Israel and compare it to your solution.

Comment: Ah, I was just trying to understand where the $r_0^2$ went in your solution. Thanks for your effort. You helped me a lot.